# Validar el tamaño de una imagen en javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo el código que detecta el tamaño de una imagen en javascript y me gustaría saber cómo puedo hacer para que si pasa del tamaño del archivo no haga el envío del archivo utilizando el form?

El código es el siguiente:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>API de Archivos con Javascript</title>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){
   /* Valida el tamaño maximo de un archivo adjunto */
   $('.input-file').change(function (){
     var sizeByte = this.files[0].size;
     var siezekiloByte = parseInt(sizeByte / 1024);

     if(siezekiloByte > $(this).attr('size')){
         alert('El tamaño supera el limite permitido');
         $(this).val('');
     }
   });
});
</script>
<style>
body{
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p><strong>Ejemplo</strong>: Usando API de Archivos de Javascript</p>
<div class="example">
    <input type="file" name="archivo" class="input-file" size="5120" >
    <div id="list"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Puedes agregar

```
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validarImagen();">
    <input type="file" class="input-file" id="imagen" name="archivo" size="1">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
function validarImagen() {
    var fileSize = $('#imagen')[0].files[0].size;
    var siezekiloByte = parseInt(fileSize / 1024);
    if (siezekiloByte >  $('#imagen').attr('size')) {
        alert("Imagen muy grande");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Existen varias soluciones, este es un ejemplo basado en tu [código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/34216/95):

```js
//Carga archivo, determina propiedades y valida tamano.
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
$("#file").change(function(e) {   
     var image, file;

      if ((file = this.files[0])) {

       var sizeByte = this.files[0].size;
       var sizekiloBytes = parseInt(sizeByte / 1024);
    
        image = new Image();
        
        image.onload = function() {           
            document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = 'Datos imagen: tamano = ' + sizekiloBytes  + ' KB , ancho (width) = ' + this.width + ' , altura (height) = ' + this.height;

        if(sizekiloBytes > $('#file').attr('size')){
              alert('El tamaño supera el limite permitido!');
           $(this).val('');
        }else{
          alert('El tamaño es permitido (menor a ' + $('#file').attr('size') + ' KB)');
        }


        };
    
        image.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);

    }

});

  //Valida envio.
   $('#form').submit(function() {
  var fileSize = $('#file')[0].files[0].size;
  var sizekiloBytes = parseInt(fileSize / 1024);
  if (sizekiloBytes >  $('#file').attr('size')) {
      alert('El tamaño supera el limite permitido!');
      return false;
  }
});
```

```css
body{
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><strong>Ejemplo</strong>: Usando API de Archivos de Javascript</p>
<div class="example">

   <form id="form" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input type="file" id="file" name="archivo" class="input-file" size="5120" >
     <p id="data"></p>
       <input type="submit" id="enviar" value="Enviar.">
    </form>
    <div id="list"></div>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]